# Metal Sampler ::linear doesn't work as expected

Tags: core-graphics, core-animation, metal

My source image is a 512x512 pixels checkerboard (see source image). When I render it to 1/3 of its size (170,6.. x 170,6..) the result looks like it is downsized with the ::nearest filter. I expect the resulting image to be an approximation of texels (colors) sampled by the sampler in my texture shader, but it is not. I tried to do the same using CALayer, and the result was identical. However, resizing NSImage created with my source image (512x512) to 1/3.0 of size produced the expected result (see image below). Please, could you explain how the sampler in Metal works  and what I need to change to get the result I expect?
Thank you.

(I render to CAMetalLayer's drawable, contentsScale @1x, displayScale @1x)

My texture shader sampler: `constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear, min_filter::linear);`

Source image 512x512: [image]

Result 170,6.. x 170,6..: [image: 512x512]
Expected result 170,6.. x 170,6..: [image]

Comment: Set your min filter to GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR

Comment: I am using METAL framework, not OpenGL, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR is constant defined in OpenGL ES.

Comment: ..and, I have to add the similar code works correctly in the OpenGL. I am porting old OpenGL code to Metal and I kicked on this.

Comment: You were actually correct: sampler needs to set with: 
constexpr sampler samplerLinear(min_filter::linear, mag_filter::linear, mip_filter::linear); I didn't generate mipmaps as I thought the linear filtering in this case can be generated with single (not mipmapped) texture.

Answer (score 0):

I made two mistakes:

1. I didn't create mipmaps from my source texture
2. Because I didn't create mipmaps and I didn't use: mip_filter::linear parameter for sampler.

Generating mipmaps and using:

`constexpr sampler samplerLinear(min_filter::linear, mag_filter::linear, mip_filter::linear);`

Renders correct output texture.